# Return the next higher number on my array and always round it up

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm trying to build a calculation spreadsheet and I hit a snag!

I'm able to use VLOOKUP to select the approximate number to my list of numbers, therefore I will always need to next number on the array.

In the case below, I have a number of 162,000,000 and I need to round up to the 250,000,000 tier. But when I use only VLOOKUP it will always round up to the closest number. The formula I used is `=VLOOKUP(C15,G17:G29, 1)`

I tried with using MAX in middle as well and also the basic LOOKUP but it didn't work.

Can anyone shed a light on my problem?

Thanks in advance!

As you can see, it always return 150,000,000:
[image: screen grab from Google Sheets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You could go with `xlookup` utilising `match-mode` parameter:*

```js
=xlookup(C15,G17:G29,G17:G29,,1)
```